# Retrieve AWS EC2s CPUUtilization using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm building a small app where I need retrieve AWS EC2s CPUUtilization using NodeJS.
I'm new to AWS so I'm reading the documentation in the following links:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/cloudwatch-examples-getting-metrics.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cloudwatch/classes/listmetricscommand.html

I'm able to send the command but I do not get the data requested (CPUUtilization in the past hour.)
I'm getting as response the following:

```
Success. Metrics: [{"Namespace":"AWS/EC2","MetricName":"CPUUtilization","Dimensions":[{"Name":"InstanceId","Value":"i-0a86544205999b1cf"}]}]
```

My code is as follows:

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const config = require("config");
const { cpuData } = require("./routes/cpuData");
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/api/cpu", cpuData);

if (
  !config.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID") ||
  !config.get("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY") ||
  !config.get("region")
) {
  console.log(
    "FATAL ERROR: Either accessID, accessKey or region are not defined.."
  );
  process.exit(1);
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(3000, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));
```

cpuData.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const getCPUUtilization = require("../startup/amazon");

//GET CPU usage
router.get("", async (req, res) => {
  const data = req.body;
  const { IP, timePeriod, interval } = data;
  console.log({ IP, timePeriod, interval });
  getCPUUtilization(IP, timePeriod, interval);
  res.send(data);
});

exports.cpuData = router;
```

amazon.js

```
const {
  CloudWatchClient,
  ListMetricsCommand,
  GetMetricData,
  GetMetricStatistics,
} = require("@aws-sdk/client-cloudwatch");
const config = require("config");

const AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID");
const AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config.get("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY");
const region = config.get("region");

const cwClient = new CloudWatchClient({
  region: region,
});

const startTime = new Date(Date.now() - 3600000);
const now = new Date();

const params = {
  Namespace: "AWS/EC2",
  MetricName: "CPUUtilization",
  Period: 3600,
  Unit: "Percent",
  StartTime: startTime.toISOString(),
  EndTime: now.toISOString(),
};

const getCPUUtilization = async (IP, timePeriod, interval) => {
  try {
    const data = await cwClient.send(new ListMetricsCommand(params));
    console.log("Success. Metrics:", JSON.stringify(data.Metrics));
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  }
};

module.exports = getCPUUtilization;
```

I also tried using the GetMetricStatisticsCommand as follows in the amazon.js file:

```
const {
  CloudWatchClient,
  ListMetricsCommand,
  GetMetricDataCommand,
  GetMetricStatisticsCommand,
} = require("@aws-sdk/client-cloudwatch");
const config = require("config");

const AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID");
const AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config.get("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY");
const region = config.get("region");

const cwClient = new CloudWatchClient({
  region: region,
});

const startTime = new Date(Date.now() - 3600000);
const now = new Date();

const params = {
  Namespace: "AWS/EC2",
  MetricName: "CPUUtilization",
  Period: 3600,
  Unit: "Percent",
  StartTime: startTime,
  EndTime: now,
  Statistics: ["Maximum", "Minimum", "Average"],
};

const getCPUUtilization = async (IP, timePeriod, interval) => {
  try {
    const data = await cwClient.send(new GetMetricStatisticsCommand(params));
    console.log("Success. Metrics:", JSON.stringify(data));
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  }
};

module.exports = getCPUUtilization;
```

With the response being:

```
Success. Metrics: {"$metadata":{"httpStatusCode":200,"requestId":"819242a8-0c90-4173-97d4-cc4ec6b55dc8","attempts":1,"totalRetryDelay":0},"Label":"CPUUtilization","Datapoints":[]}
```

Still no data.

What I'm missing to be able to get the CPUUtilization of the period I set on the StartTime and end Time of my params?

Also I wish to send the IP address of the instance I wish to retrieve the data from but I cannot find in the documentation information about this.
This may be the parameter I'm missing.

If someone could point me to this documentation or a small example I'll appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I saw what I was missing.
In params I was missing the Dimensions parameter

```
const params = {
  Dimensions: [
    {
      Name: "InstanceId",
      Value: "i-xxxxxx", // where xxxx is string value
    },
  ],
  Namespace: "AWS/EC2",
  MetricName: "CPUUtilization",
  Period: 60,
  Unit: "Percent",
  StartTime: startTime,
  EndTime: now,
  Statistics: ["Maximum", "Minimum", "Average"],
};
```

Now I get data in datapoints

Current response:

```
Success. Metrics: {"$metadata":{"httpStatusCode":200,"requestId":"f161e1ac-b3e0-478c-be64-54a46ac987a9","attempts":1,"totalRetryDelay":0},"Label":"CPUUtilization","Datapoints":[{"Timestamp":"2021-12-08T18:25:00.000Z","Average":0.2833352224111132,"Minimum":0.28332388920369317,"Maximum":0.2833427780926031,"Unit":"Percent"},{"Timestamp":"2021-12-08T19:00:00.000Z","Average":0.3458356946759311,"Minimum":0.3250108336944565,"Maximum":0.3666605556574057,"Unit":"Percent"},{"Timestamp":"2021-12-08T18:15:00.000Z","Average":0.29333630580047193,"Minimum":0.2916618056365727,"Maximum":0.3000100003333444,"Unit":"Percent"},{"Timestamp":"2021-12-08T18:10:00.000Z","Average":0.30666350022036776,"Minimum":0.2916666666666667,"Maximum":0.33332777787036877,"Unit":"Percent"},{"Timestamp":"2021-12-08T18:45:00.000Z","Average":0.2983333333657407,"Minimum":0.2916618056365727,"Maximum":0.3166666666666666,"Unit":"Percent"},{"Timestamp":"2021-12-08T18:35:00.000Z","Average":0.3599968335435113,"Minimum":0.2833191673749646,"Maximum":0.6666555557407376,"Unit":"Percent"},{"Timestamp":"2021-12-08T18:30:00.000Z","Average":0.30333219469119843,"Minimum":0.28333333333333327,"Maximum":0.34999416676388717,"Unit":"Percent"},{"Timestamp":"2021-12-08T18:20:00.000Z","Average":0.2999978056958308,"Minimum":0.2749954167430542,"Maximum":0.3416552781573947,"Unit":"Percent"},{"Timestamp":"2021-12-08T18:55:00.000Z","Average":0.3666632501624954,"Minimum":0.2916666666666667,"Maximum":0.658311389620346,"Unit":"Percent"},{"Timestamp":"2021-12-08T18:50:00.000Z","Average":0.2999998055912036,"Minimum":0.28333333333333327,"Maximum":0.34999416676388717,"Unit":"Percent"},{"Timestamp":"2021-12-08T18:05:00.000Z","Average":0.3649996945467608,"Minimum":0.27499999999999997,"Maximum":0.6749887501874969,"Unit":"Percent"},{"Timestamp":"2021-12-08T18:40:00.000Z","Average":0.3050033334277807,"Minimum":0.2916666666666667,"Maximum":0.35001166705556847,"Unit":"Percent"}]}
```

Still missing the specific IP of the instance.
If someone know if this is even possible or necessary please let me know.